# How to use hilt instead of using factory to init the argument in viewModel

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Now I using the viewModelFactory to init the argument for viewModel in fragment.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        val argument = MyFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArgument()).myArgument
        val viewModelFactory = MyViewModelFactory(myArgument, application)
        binding.viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
                this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        return binding.root
    }
}

class MyViewModelFactory(
        private val myArgument: MyArgument,
        private val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MyViewModel(myArgument, application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Compare to the hilt dependency inject way, is there a way to pass argument to viewModel directly?

Comment: Are your dependencies runtime or buildtime. If so (build time) refer to @AliSh answer. Otherwise you have to create a viewModel factory at the moment. That's because Hilt doesn't support `@AssistedInject` yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. With Hilt, you can completely ditch the factory pattern.

To inject a param, you can use `@ViewModelInject` annotation, and to inject the `viewModel` in the activity you can use the `by viewModels()` method from `androidx.activity` package.

Here's an example.

**ProductsViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
import androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelInject

class ProductsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val foo: Foo
    private val bar: Bar
) : ViewModel()
```

**ProductsActivity.kt**

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProductsActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    
    val viewModel: ProductsViewModel by viewModels()
    
}
```

To see this in action, you can checkout [this repo](https://github.com/theapache64/nemo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/theapache64/nemo/feature/products).

Comment: Very nice, could explain how to pass param foo and bar in ProductsActivity when init the ProductsViewModel.

Comment: `@ViewModelInject` is not available anymore. They should use `@HiltViewModel` intead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) library. You should first define your view model by `@HiltViewModel` and use constructor injection(`@Inject` for constructor of your view model):

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(val foo: Foo) : ViewModel()
```

My Foo class is:

```
class Foo @Inject constructor(val someDependency: Dependency)
```

If you have any other class which you need to inject to your ViewModel, you can add it to your hilt module.

Finally, you should instantiate your ViewModel in your activity/fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

Please note that we are talking only about build time dependencies. For runtime dependencies with Hilt, you still have to stick to a classic `ViewModelProvider.Factory` since `@AssistedInject` is not yet supported by it.