# How can I stop a screen from recomposing in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

I have navigation drawer where I have two items:

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = {},
    content = {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {},
            content = { padding ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(padding)
                ) {
                    when (viewModel.selectedItem) {
                        items[0] -> Home()
                        items[1] -> Products()
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Where `items` is a list that is initialized like this:

```
val items = listOf(
    Item(Icons.Default.Home, "Home"),
    Item(Icons.Default.List, "Products")
)
```

And `selectedItem` is initialized inside the ViewModel like this

```
var selectedItem by mutableStateOf(items[0])
```

Where, `Home` has this content:

```
fun Home() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        PopularProducts(
            popularProductsContent = { popularProducts ->
                HorizontalContent(
                    products = popularProducts
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And `Products` this:

```
fun Products(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.getAllProducts()
    }
    Products { products ->
        Column {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp)
            ) {
                items(products) { product ->
                    ProductCard(
                        product = product
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I launch the app, `Home` item is loaded. If I navigate away from it, and I get back, everything is alright, the page isn't recomposed. But if I select `Products`, and I navigate to the product details, for example, when I navigate back, the screen is recomposed (it blinks). Basically another request is made. How can I stop this from happening?

P.S. I use Hilt Navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `LaunchedEffect` will be getting called again which is triggering your products to reload.

You just need to cache your products somehow so that reload and reset isn't happening, there are many ways to do that with increasing complexity and architecture but the simplest fix would be just to call `viewModel.getAllProducts()` in your `MainViewModel` `init` instead of having the `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Yes, it makes sense. I just voted-up. But how about the situation, where I cannot add that to the ViewModel? Because I have something like `viewModel.getProductById(id)`. And the ID comes directly as a parameter in the composable, so I need to call it from there. How to solve that, any idea?

Comment: The easiest way would just be to check if you've already loaded the product and not load it again. The probably most correct answer is to use hilt and savedstatehandle but that's adding a lot of complexity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350331/how-to-use-hilt-to-inject-a-safe-args-argument-into-a-viewmodel

Comment: Hey. Maybe you can help me with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853421/how-to-stop-collectaslazypagingitems-from-firing-when-itemcount-is-0) too.