# How to stop collectAsLazyPagingItems() from firing when itemCount is 0?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a screen where I display some items using pagination. Here is what I have tried:

```
fun ItemsScreen(
    viewModel: ItemsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val items = viewModel.getItems().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
        Log.d(TAG, "itemCount is ${items.itemCount}")
    }
}
```

Here is how I call it from the ViewModel class:

```
fun getItems() = repo.getItems()
```

And here is the repo:

```
override fun getItems() = Pager(
    config = config
) {
    AppPagingSource(
        query = db.collection("items").limit(12)
    )
}.flow
```

When I open the page, I get:

```
itemCount is 0
itemCount is 12
```

So, first time I get **zero**. When the data becomes available, I get 12. How can I stop `collectAsLazyPagingItems()` from firing when the `itemCount` is zero? I only want to fire when the data is received. How to solve this?

---

### **Edit:**

Why do I need to stop collectAsLazyPagingItems() from firing?

Because the same code as above is used in a pagination. So, each time I type a character, a new request is performed, and until I get the page results, I get **zero**, and after 2 seconds I get 12.

What I want to achieve, is when I get no results because of a wrong search, I want to display a message, "No items found". But **only** then, not each time I load new data. With the code above, until I'm getting new results, that message is displayed, because `items.itemCount == 0` for 2 seconds. After that, the results are correctly displayed in the grid. Here is the logic:

```
if (items.itemCount > 0) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(...)
} else {
    if (searchText.isNotEmpty()) {
        Text("No items found")
    }
}
```

### Edit2:

```
fun getItems(searchText: String) = if (searchText.isEmpty()) {
    repo.getItems()
} else {
    repo.getSearchItems(searchText)
}.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: `pager.flow` is a Flow. You can use `Flow<List<T>>.filter{it.isNotEmpty()}` operator  to emit a flow that is not an empty list

Comment: i mean just add `pager.flow.filter{it.isNotEmpty()}` to end to flow in getItems function. Your flow won't emit a list that is empty

Comment: `I only want to fire when the data is received.` Can I ask why don't you want an empty list emission? Does it break any of your logic?

Comment: @Joan P. the problem I see is that you calling `  val items = viewModel.getItems().collectAsLazyPagingItems()` in composable scope which creates Pager flow every time composable is recomposed. This might be underlying problem

Comment: @Thracian The type of Flow that I get is `Flow<PagingData<Item>>` and **not** Flow<List<Item>>, so I cannot see any solution to filter this kind of data. Is there any way I can filter this kind of Flow?

Comment: I haven't used Pager for a long time but i checked documents. PagingData has a filter operator too. You can use it inside Flow.map{} i assume. I will check out tonight  and will make a sample to see. I'd rather doing it with a reactive approach if possible. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingData#(androidx.paging.PagingData).filter(kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)

Comment: @Thracian The filter function you are referring is for filtering out elements in the paging list as you can see from the signature it takes `predicate: suspend (T) -> Boolean`.  I don't think it can be used to filter out empty list emissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I stop collectAsLazyPagingItems() from firing when the itemCount is zero?

You can't. Following is a section from the [source code](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/paging/paging-compose/1.0.0-alpha16-source/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems.kt.html):

[image]

When you call `items.itemCount` it gives you the size of `itemSnapshotList` which is initialized with an `emptyList` in the beginning. Think of the paging items as a state instead of an event which is fired. A state has always some value associated with it.

Although I believe that an empty list emission shouldn't cause any problem in general but if you really don't want to process that value, the only option is to ignore it by an `if` statement like this:

```kotlin
val items = viewModel.getItems().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
if(items.itemCount > 0) {
    // UI goes here
}
// Some other UI
```

Or you can also return from the composable, if there's nothing to show in case of empty list.

```kotlin
val items = viewModel.getItems().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
if(items.itemCount == 0)
    return
// UI goes here
```

**Edit:** You can use `items.loadState.refresh` to check if the data is being refreshed. The updated code will look like this:

```kotlin
when {
    items.loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
    items.itemCount > 0 -> {
        LazyVerticalGrid(...)
    }
    searchText.isNotEmpty() -> {
        Text("No items found")
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your solution, but it doesn't work the way I need. Please see my updated question. Maybe it's clearer now. Thanks again. Voted up.

Comment: @JoanP. Can you also add in the question how do you re-trigger new paging data when search query changes?

Comment: @JoanP. I have edited the answer (assuming you call `items.refresh()` for loading new data). See if this solves your problem.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you. Btw, just updated the question with the data request in your comment.

Comment: I'm not calling `items.refresh()`, I just create another database request. I see that there are two states, `refresh` and `append`. So, am I not appending, since it's a new call, or am I refreshing? I'm a little confused. How to use the append? I think that we are very close. Thanks again for supporting me.

Comment: `refresh` is when you refresh entire list. `append` is (as the name suggests) fetching more elements at the bottom of the list. For example, as you scroll through the list, more elements are fetched by the paging library to be appended to the list. When this happens `append` is in `LoadState.Loading`. I guess you don't need the `append` state here.

Comment: Oh, right. So, it's about appending, and not refreshing. While scrolling I add more items to the list, right? Let me try it once again and get back to you.

Comment: As I understand I don't append items at the end of the list, but refreshing the entire list, right? Since it works with refresh and not with append, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, when you enter a new query and get a new `Pager`, you are in the refresh state until you get the first part of new list.